In Java Hashmap key changes when it is a mutable list, why?
Hashmap is expected to work normally and only way to rename key is to remove it first and add new key with same value. But this rule is broken when key is list of elements and we, for example, add elements to the list. The map is now totally changed???
Due to this I'm getting null pointer as the old list is not passing equals()

could you please show a minimal reproducible example? Also, I would recommend not calling .equals on a List itself

The only way to change a key without breaking the map is to remove it and re-add it.  You have broken your map, and found out what happens when you do.

@Stultuske "Also, I would recommend not calling .equals on a List itself" - Why not? List.equals() is well defined and does what I'd expect it to do.

@Sören call it a personal choice. In most uses cases (at least in my experience), we want to check if two lists contain the same elements, so: [A, B] for that case is basically equal to [B, A], but calling equals on a List also whether or not the order of elements is identical, which may lead to issues.
